# Powershell video length calculation

Tags: powershell, datetime, calculation

I have a calculation issue I cannot solve, any help appreciated! I receive video length of files in a more complex loop context using the following code:

```
$movs ="..\..\MOV"
        $dura = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
        $dura = Get-ChildItem -Path $movs -Recurse -Force | ForEach {
            $Folder = $Shell.Namespace($_.DirectoryName)
            $File = $Folder.ParseName($_.Name)
            $Duration = $Folder.GetDetailsOf($File, 27)
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                vid-file= $_.Name -replace ".mov",""
                duration = $Duration
            }
        }
```

Later on I match some IDs to $dura so that the result looks like this:

```
ID  vid-file    duration
1   move        00:01:08
1   run         00:01:12
1   fly         00:01:30
1   swim        00:01:08
1   sleep       00:02:20
2   move        00:01:08
2   swim        00:01:08
2   sleep       00:02:20
3   move        00:01:08
3   run         00:01:12
3   fly         00:01:30
3   swim        00:01:08
3   sleep       00:02:20
3   think       00:03:20
```

Now I need to calculate the starting points for each concatenated video case, i.e. I have to sum up the duration of the video for each part until the current position for every ID context and create a new column with it (every new ID starts at 00:00:00). The result would look like this:

```
ID  vid-file    duration    videopart-start-at
1   move        00:01:08    00:00:00
1   run         00:01:12    00:01:08
1   fly         00:01:30    00:02:20
1   swim        00:01:08    00:03:50
1   sleep       00:02:20    00:04:58
2   move        00:01:08    00:00:00
2   swim        00:01:08    00:01:08
2   sleep       00:02:20    00:02:16
3   move        00:01:08    00:00:00
3   run         00:01:12    00:01:08
3   fly         00:01:30    00:02:20
3   swim        00:01:08    00:03:50
3   sleep       00:02:20    00:04:58
3   think       00:03:20    00:07:18
```

I think there could be some calculated object in the PSCustomObject but I can't figure it out..

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
                vid-file= $_.Name -replace ".mov",""
                duration = $Duration
                videopart-start-at= $Duration | Measure-Object -Sum $Duration
            }
```

Thanks, Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sebastian I found the following solution (I added the "startat" column in the pscustomobject, identical to durationinseconds):

```
        
$i = 0
Foreach ($object in $result) {
    
    # skip lines gt result count
    if ($i -gt ($result.count)) {
        $i++
        continue
    }
    
    # set start to 0 for first line          
    if ($i -eq 0) {
        $object.startat = 0
    }   

    # calculate start time for all following lines
    if ($i -gt 0) {
        $object.startat = $result.durationinseconds[$i - 1] + $result.startat[$i - 1]
    } 

    # transform seconds to time value in duration var
    $object.duration = [timespan]::fromseconds($object.startat)

    # counter +1
    $i++

}

$result
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think that there's an easier way of handling this - but I converted the time into seconds - then worked on the [TimeSpan] datatype.

```
$movs = 'c:\temp\sample' | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Stop
        
$dura = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$result = Foreach ($mov in $movs) {
    $Folder = $dura.Namespace($mov.DirectoryName)
    $File = $Folder.ParseName($mov.Name)
    $Duration = $Folder.GetDetailsOf($File, 27)
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        vidfile           = $mov.Name -replace ".mov", ""
        # Convert the string into an actual time data type
        duration          = $Duration
        durationinseconds = ([TimeSpan]::Parse($Duration)).TotalSeconds  
    }
} 
        
$i = 0
Foreach ($object in $result) {
    # Skipping first and stopping on last (foreach will run out of objects to process)
            
    if ($i -eq 0 -or $i -gt ($result.count)) {
        # Adding one to counter
        $i++
        continue
    }

    $object.durationinseconds = $Object.durationinseconds + $result.durationinseconds[$i - 1]
    $object.duration = [timespan]::fromseconds($object.durationinseconds)
    ("{0:hh\:mm\:ss}" -f $object.duration)
    $i++

}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you @sebastian-wiszowaty for hinting me to the right solution. I followed your suggestions and changed your code so that the first line is set to zero (the actual starting point of the first part of the video) and the following values are calculated from the previous ones. What helped me very much is the construction with counting $i in a foreach cycle as well as to refer the previous value with $result.durationinseconds[$i - 1] . I will add my solution as answer below.

Comment: Sounds great :)!

Answer (score 0):

To calculate date/time differences, try something like this...

```
$current = Get-Date
$end     = (Get-Date).AddHours(1)
$diff    = New-TimeSpan -Start $current -End $end
"The time difference is: $diff"
# Results
<#
The time difference is: 01:00:00.0019997
#>
```

... then format as you need to.